# Error -1001 in clGetPlatformIDs Call !

Tags: opencl, nvidia

I am trying to start working with OpenCL. I have two NVidia graphics card, I installed "developer driver" as well as SDK from NVidia website. I compiled the demos but when I run

./oclDeviceQuery

I see:

> OpenCL SW Info:
>
> Error -1001 in clGetPlatformIDs Call
>   !!!

How can I fix it? Does it mean my nvidia cards cannot be detected? I am running Ubuntu 10.10 and X server works properly with nvidia driver.

I am pretty sure the problem is not related to file permissions as it doesn't work with sudo either.

Comment: Its been 7 years since this question was first asked. I still have the same problem. Did you find a solution yet

Answer (score 9):

In my case I have solved it by installing **nvidia-modprobe** package available in ubuntu (utopic/multiverse). And the driver itself (v346) was installed from
 https://launchpad.net/~mamarley/+archive/ubuntu/nvidia
Concretely, I have installed nvidia-opencl-icd-346, nvidia-libopencl1-346, nvidia-346-uvm, nvidia-346 and libcuda1-346. Not sure if they are all needed for OpenCL.

Comment: In my case nvidia-modprobe was the problem. Now it works even with the old driver (331). Thanks!

Comment: Made it work for me on Ubuntu 15.10, exact setup explained at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33483311/895245

Answer (score 7):

This is a result of not installing the ICD portion of Nvidia's openCL runtime.  The ICD profile will instruct your application of the different openCL implementations installed on the system as multiple implementations from different vendors can coexist.  Whe your application does not find the ICD information it gives the Error -1001.

Comment: Could you tell me more about what exactly is missing? I have /etc/OpenCL/vendors/nvidia.icd file which refers to libcuda.so library. The library itself exists and is on LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Answer (score 3):

Run your program as root. In case of success: you have trouble with cl_khr_icd- extension to load the vendor driver.
If you not running X11, you have to create device files manually or by (boot-)script:
[ERROR: clGetPlatformIDs -1001 when running OpenCL code (Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20335579/error-clgetplatformids-1001-when-running-opencl-code-linux?lq=1)

Answer (score 2):

Same problem for me on a Linux system. Solution is to add the user to the video group:

```
# sudo usermod -aG video your-user-name
```

Comment: That doesn't help! At least not for me, and I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since I just spend a couple of hours on this, I thought I would share:
I got the error because I was connected to the machine per remote desktop (mstsc). On the machine itself everything worked fine.

I have been told that it should work with TeamViewer by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Dont know if you ever solved this problem, but I had the same issue and solved it in this post: [ERROR: clGetPlatformIDs -1001 when running OpenCL code (Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20335579/error-clgetplatformids-1001-when-running-opencl-code-linux/20336286#20336286)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it in Ubuntu 13.10 saucy for intel opencl by created link:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/intel/opencl-1.2-3.2.1.16712/etc/intel64.icd /etc/OpenCL/vendors/nvidia.icd
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem on ubuntu 14.04 and I could not find ANY working answers anywhere online including this thread (though this was the first to show up on google). What ended up working for me was to remove ALL previous nvidia software and then to reinstall it using the .run file provided on the nvidia website. Installing the components through apt-get seems to fail for some reason.

1) Download CUDA .run file: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads

2) Purge all previous nvidia packages

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
```

3) Install all run file components (you will likely have to stop X or restart in recovery mode to run this)

```
sudo sh cuda_X.X.XX_linux.run
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because OpenCL has the same brain damaged one library per vendor setup that OpenGL has. A likely reason for the -1001 error is that you have compiled with a different library than the linker is trying to dynamically load.

So see if this is the problem run:

```
$ ldd oclDeviceQuery        
        ...
        libOpenCL.so.1 => important path here (0x00007fe2c17fb000)
        ...
```

Does the path point towards the NVidia-provided libOpenCL.so.1 file? If it doesn't, you should recompile the program with an `-L` parameter pointing towards the directory containing NVidia's libOpenCL.so.1. If you can't do that, you can override the linker's path like this:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/nvidias/lib ./oclDeviceQuery
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was missing the CUDA OpenCL library, Running `sudo apt install cuda-opencl-dev-12-0` solved it.

Answer (score -2):

You should get number of platforms, allocate the memory for platforms, again get this platforms and then create context from this platform. There is good example:
http://developer.amd.com/support/KnowledgeBase/Lists/KnowledgeBase/DispForm.aspx?ID=71

Answer (score -2):

This might be due to querying clGetPlatformIDs by multiple threads at the same time