# Can't use opencl in Metro Style Project(WINRT)

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, opencl

I'm writing code under WIN8(Metro style app), and having issues using OpenCL.

My project runs very well when I compile and run it as a WIN8 desktop app.
But when I change it to Win store app(Metro style), then I can't use the OpenCL any more.

```
//get platform id
error = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platformID, &numPlatforms);

if(error != CL_SUCCESS)
    return;
```

clGetPlatformIDs returns error code `-1001`.

Can't I use OpenCL in Metro style app? Someone please  help me figure the issue out. I'm a WIN8 newbie

Answer (score 0):

Error code -1001 usually means your driver is correctly installed , but the opencl runtime not is not configured/installed properly.

You can try various thing ...

1) Make sure you got updated driver installed and is not outdated (if you see problem with latest driver you can retry with previous version also)?

2) Completely remove current driver and install it again.

Comment: Great advice on how to solve ICD/driver issues (also covered in this SO item: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959621/error-1001-in-clgetplatformids-call) but for the bounty that I added I'm also looking for clear evidence that OpenCL **should** work and is fully supported in a WinRT / Metro Style Application.