# Opencl clGetPlatformIDs error -1001

Tags: opencl

I am trying to run some OpenCL programs. 
I have a NVidia graphics card (GeForce 6600).

But , when I execute my program and I get a error : 
 Unable to get platforms -1001

My OS is ArchLinux and I already install the following packages (
from pacman ):
1. libcl
2. opencl-headers
3. opencl-nvidia-304xx
4. lib32-opencl-nvidia-304xx

How to fix this problem in my environment？
or what necessary packages need to install?

thanks.

Comment: Check out this answer this was asked earlier this week: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29171558/opencl-not-finding-platforms/29175174?noredirect=1#comment46754767_29175174 Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks pasternak, but even thoung I install cuda toolkit, it will get same error in my environment. Could any method to check I intsall right package or check the opencl link is available?

Answer (score 0):

`OpenCL-error -1001 "CL_PLATFORM_NOT_FOUND_KHR"` doesn't necessarily mean you don't have any OpenCL-capable device. This means, that `cl_khr_icd-extention` have a trouble to load the proper vendor driver. 
Try to run your OpenCL-program(s) as root. Or try to use `clIcdGetPlatformIDsKHR`.
If you not running X11, you need to create device files manually or by script